# Where can I download i686 RedHat 4 bash package?

Tags: bash, rhel

https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-1293.html

The offical announce is only starting at RHEL 5. There are no packages for RHEL4? According to Wikipedia, it's still supported until the start of 2015.

Comment: Buy an Extended Life Cycle Support licence and then you can add an additional channel to update your bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry for RHEL4 on the [table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#Product_life_cycle) indicates "28 February 2015" as the end of "Extended Life Phase", the end of "Production 3 Phase" was 29 February 2012. During that extended phase, between those dates, there is support  only for customers that "pay an additional subscription" (and that for a subset of packages). This is clearly indicated in the text above the table.

Of course those upgrades during extended life are not freely available. If you are a paying customer contact Red-Hat directly. If you are not a paying customer, and if this is a production server, I suggest upgrading ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Cyrus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/74329/cyrus), you are better off buying an Extended Life Cycle Support licence. The RedHat patch is AFAIK superior to the one provided by Mr.Ramey.

---

However, the easy way (if you aren't on paid support) is to roll your own bash package:

- Install [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm)
- Download the source file (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.0.tar.gz)
- Download all patches (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.0-patches/)
- `tar xzvf bash-3.0.tar.gz`
- Apply all patches, including the latest `patch -p0 <bash30-019`
- `./configure --prefix=/usr`
- `make`
- `mkdir -p /tmp/bash`
- `make install DESTDIR=/tmp/bash`
- `mkdir -p /tmp/bash/bin`
- `mv /tmp/bash/usr/bin/bash /tmp/bash/bin/bash`
- `rm /tmp/bash/usr/share/info/dir`
- `ln -s /bin/bash /tmp/bash/bin/sh`
- Add a `tmp/bash/etc/skel`directory with suitable templates
- `fpm -s dir -t rpm --epoch 1 -n bash -v 3.0.19 -p bash-3.0.19-1.rpm -C /tmp/bash .`
- `yum install bash-3.0.19-1.rpm`

Comment: @somelooser28533 - glad it helped.